# extracting data from diverse HTML tables

Tags: python, html, html-table

I'm trying to extract data from Income Statements tables in 8-K Forms from Edgar Database (http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html). Here are some examples:

[Apple](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312512435506/d429806dex991.htm)

[Alcoa](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4281/000119312512423191/d424171dex992.htm)

The tables I want to scrape are called 'STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS' or 'Statements of Income' or similar. I try to extract all data (like net sales, operating income etc.) and put it into dictionaries according to dates and time intervals (three months, six months etc.). The problem is high diversity of tables structure - there are a lot of ways in which such data can be structured. I created a script that parses tables using Beautiful Soup, but it's getting big and complex. I wonder if there is any way to get it right away (with all its complexity) without a lot of coding? I tried to use Excel and Google Docs to get data automatically, but they perform poorly in this case. Any suggestions?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd get all the tables into a straightforward data structure using BeautifulSoup first, and then try to extract what you want. The two example pages you give don't contain any `<th>` elements, so for those, you can handle the basic extraction like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def tables(html):
    """Extract all tables from `html`."""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return [[
            [cell.text for cell in row.findAll("td")]
            for row in table.findAll("tr")]
        for table in soup.findAll("table")]
```

... which will give you a list of tables, each of which is a list of rows, each of which is a list of cells.

**Caveat**: if there are nested tables lurking around, the code above will likely go horribly wrong.

You could get `<th>` elements as well by changing one line ...

```
            [cell.text for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"])]
```

... but then you'd obviously lose the distinction between `<th>` and `<td>` cells. Given the state of your source material, that might not be such a great loss.

Actually getting what you need out of there programmatically is another matter ... you might be better off just dumping each table into a CSV file and then working with that via a spreadsheet application.